# calling constructor when creating an array of objects

Tags: c++

If, say I want to dynamically allocate an array of objects with new operator like

```
Some_Class* p=new Some_Class[10];
```

Will the default constructor be called? Or, it will just allocate some memory space for 10 such objects, without specifying any information about the objects? Since the

```
Some_Class* q=new Some_Class;
```

will call the default constructor.

Comment: _"Will the default constructor be called?"_ Yes.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ      So that means it will instantiate an array of such objects?

Comment: Yes it will. Read the answers in the linked duplicate, all you need to know can be found there.